# How Can I mock JdbcDaoImpl in test using mockito

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-security, mockito

I need to mock `JdbcDaoImpl` class to test my unit authentications tests. My `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` child class configurations are

```
@Autowired
private AnalyticsUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource);
}

@Autowired
public void configureAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
    authenticationManagerBuilder
            .userDetailsService(this.userDetailsService)
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

    //this configuration is for checking app resources
    //this is not a regular authentication process
    //it will look for user in users and authorities table in db
    authenticationManagerBuilder.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource);
}
```

My Test class:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = SpringConfig.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@AutoConfigureWebMvc
@TestExecutionListeners(MockitoTestExecutionListener.class)
public class AuthenticationTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests{
    private static final String KNOWN_USER_MAIL = "valerian@mail.com";
    private static final String KNOWN_USER_PASSWORD = "pa$$w0rd";
    private static final String IN_MEMORY_KNOWN_USER_MAIL = "memuser";
    private static final String IN_MEMORY_KNOWN_USER_PASSWORD = "pass";

    @MockBean
    private AuthenticationUserService authenticationUserService;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;


    @Test
    public void successLoginTest() throws Exception{
        Mockito.when(authenticationUserService.getUser(KNOWN_USER_MAIL)).thenReturn(createdUser(UserAccountRole.ROLE_SUPER));
        Answer<Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority>> answers = (invocationOnMock) -> getRoles();

        Mockito.when(authenticationUserService.getAuthorities(KNOWN_USER_MAIL)).thenAnswer(answers);
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JwtAuthenticationRequest loginInfo = new JwtAuthenticationRequest(KNOWN_USER_MAIL, KNOWN_USER_PASSWORD);

        MockHttpServletRequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/auth")
                .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(loginInfo));

        mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder).andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.cookie().exists(ACCESS_TOKEN));
    }
}
```

if I comment `configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)` method and `authenticationManagerBuilder.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)` from my web security config class, the above test passes. however if I un-comment the code it throws below exception. How can I mock `JdbcDaoImpl` class so that its `loadUserByUsername(username)` method return expected user instead of hitting db which is not available. I tried `@MockBean JdbcDaoImpl jdbcDaoImpl` but its not working.

```
org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

Comment: You could use an in-memory database like HSQL for tests.

Comment: can you give example?